# Describe image under mapping $w=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ of set $\{z=x+iy : x>0, y>0 \}$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I'm new to complex analysis. In polar form, when I plug in a general $z=re^{i\theta}$ to $w$, I end up with $$w(z)=\dfrac{r^2-2ir\cos\theta-1}{r^2+2r\sin\theta+1}$$

I know since $x,y>0$, I have $0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$, but that's all I can tell.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: The image of the imaginary axis is the real axis and the image of the real axis is a circle which goes through $w(0)$ and $w(\infty)$ and is orthogonal to the real axis. The four resulting regions are the images of the four quadrants.

Comment: @Maxim Since the domain is restricted by $0 < x,y$, neither the real or the imaginary axes are in the domain.  The domain is the 1st quadrant only.

Comment: @user2661923 The image of the boundary under a Mobius transformation is the boundary of the image.

Comment: @Maxim Never occurred to me.  Perhaps Palka will be covering this in a later chapter.  In any event, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite $w=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ as $z = i\frac{1+w}{1-w} =re^{i\theta}, \theta\in (0,\frac\pi2)$. Then
$$e^{i2\theta} =\frac{z}{\bar z} =  \frac{i\frac{1+w}{1-w}}{-i\frac{1+\bar w}{1-\bar w}}
= -\frac{(1-\bar w)(1+w)}{(1+\bar w)(1-w)}\implies
|w - i\tan\theta |^2 = \sec^2\theta$$
which represents a family of circles with center $i\tan\theta$ and radius $\sec\theta$. Thus, along with $\text{Im}(w)=\frac{-2r\cos\theta}{r^2+2r\sin\theta+1}<0$, the image is a half unit-disk, the shaded area below.
[image]

Comment: This cannot be correct because $w$ is bounded in the first quadrant.

Comment: @Maxim - $z$ is bounded in the first quadrant, not $w$. $w$ is its image

Comment: Not contained in the first quadrant, bounded in the sense of being a bounded function.

Comment: @Zebramuscles1234 From the OP: "I'm new to complex analysis." Quanto, is your analysis what a book/teacher would expect from someone new to Complex Analysis?  Based on the OP's comments throughout this webpage, it is almost as if the OP wandered into a Complex Analysis course in the middle of a semester, and is attacking a complicated problem, almost *from scratch*.

Comment: @user2661923 - The question belongs to an important topic, i.e. the Mobius mapping, in complex analysis. It is not an advanced subject. As seen in the answer, the technique involved is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bilinear or Mobius transformation. f(z) = $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. I'm a fan of Linear Geometry by Rafael Artzy, which covers this in detail.  For example, f(z) = az+b has w = b/(1-a) as an invariant (fixed) point.  It is a rotation through angle a about w.  An inversion is N(z) = 1/z. A translation T(z) = z+b is labeled $T_b$. If $\delta = ad-bc$, and f = $\frac{-\delta}{c^2}$, then a dilatation is $D_f$ and the full Mobius transformation B = $T_{d/c} N D_f T_{a/c} $. For your example, $\delta = 2i$.
Mobius transformations map the set of all straight lines and circles into the set of all straight lines and circles.

Answer (score 0):

Why even bother with polar coordinates?

$$w = \frac{x +(y-1)i}{x + (y+1)i} \times 
\frac{x -(y+1)i}{x - (y+1)i} ~=~
\frac{(x^2 + 1 - y^2) - i(2x)}{x^2 + (y+1)^2}.\tag1$$

Note that by multiplying through by the complex conjugate of the denominator, I created a fraction whose denominator is a real number.

**Addendum**
Per OP's request
Under the assumption that $(x + iy) = z = re^{i\theta}$ convert equation (1) into polar coordinates, involving $r$ and $\theta$.

This is extremely ugly.  Frankly, the analysis in RobertTheTutor's answer is way over my head, so my approach would be to do things **from scratch**.

Since the original constraint is $0 < x,y$, you can assume that $0 < \theta < (\pi/2).$

Further, you have that $r^2 = |z|^2 = (x^2 + y^2)$,
while
$|w|^2 = \frac{(x^2 + 1 - y^2)^2 + 4x^2}{[x^2 + (y+1)^2]^2}.$

Assuming that you wish to express $w = se^{i\alpha}$,
you will have that $s^2 = |w|^2$ and that $\alpha$ is the unique angle, within a modulus of $(2\pi)$ such that

$\cos(\alpha) = \frac{x^2 + 1 - y^2}{|t|}$ and
$\sin(\alpha) = \frac{-2x}{|t|},~$ where
$t^2 = (x^2 + 1 - y^2)^2 + (-2x)^2.$

Here, since $r^2 = (x^2 + y^2)$, and since $\cos(\theta) = \frac{x}{r}, \sin(\theta) = \frac{y}{r}$, the challenge would be to somehow:

first express $s$ in terms of $(r)$ and trig functions involving $(\theta)$ and then express $\cos(\alpha), \sin(\alpha)$ in terms of $s,r$ and trig functions involving $(\theta).$

My response is based on nothing more than my surviving Chapter 1 of "An Introduction To Complex Function Theory" (Bruce Palka).  Palka does discuss mobius transformations, but the pertinent problems (involving mobius transformations) at the back of chapter 1 are structured very narrowly.

Palka does mention that he will discuss mobius transformations in later chapters, but it is a safe bet that this is no walk in the park.  I question the intent of your instructor.

Do you really think that if $z = re^{i\theta}$, that (for example) either $(z - i)$ or $\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ would be so easily expressible in polar coordinates involving $r$ and $\theta$?

If there is an elegant way to do this, I'd certainly like it explained to me, in terms compatible with someone who has only survived chapter 1 of the book.

This addendum is nothing more than an elaboration that if an expression for $w$ is required in polar coordinates involving $r$ and $(\theta)$ then I am **way out of my depth**.

About the only thing that I can say for sure, is that based on equation (1) above, $\sin(\alpha) < 0$, and the sign of $\cos(\alpha)$ will obviously be based on the sign of the expression $(x^2 + 1 - y^2).$

A cursory examination of equation (1) above does not yield any obvious insights to me, re constraints on $|w|^2.$

Comment: is there some way to know whether polar or rectangular coordinates are better in a particular situation?

Comment: I got the same thing as you when I used rectangular coordinates and I understand the denominator is a real number, but where do I take it from there?

Comment: @Zebramuscles1234 Yes, by trying both ways, and seeing where it leads.  After you've done 50 problems like this, you'll be able to tell at a glance which way to go.

Comment: @Zebramuscles1234 "...but where do I take it from there?"  You don't take it anywhere.  The answer I provided is the **final** answer.  Your query said nothing about requiring that the answer be expressed in polar coordinates.   An answer in polar coordinates is certainly do-able but troublesome.  What was the **intent** of the original problem?

Comment: my book often interprets the solution set geometrically like the region inside the unit disk or the upper half of the plane, etc. So I assumed I also needed to provide some information like that

Comment: @Zebramuscles1234 See the Addendum that I just added to my answer.